# How I can play animations anijs Angular templates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, plugins, jquery-animate

I used the following label to encourage an item and works:

 `<img src="assets/img/logo.png" data-anijs="if: load, on: window, do: zoomIn animated">`

But when my templates to integrate " Angular " is not working.
I have been researching and found the following:

 `<img src="assets/img/logo.png" data-anijs="if: DOMContentLoaded, on: document, do: zoomIn animated">`

Unfortunately it does not work either, I could help.

Source: http://regularjs.github.io/blog/2014/07/26/2014-7-26-animation-rethink/#Angular

Comment: scripts that are dependent on domContentLoaded are not practical in angular. Angular already has animations built in when you include `ngAnimate`...suggest reading up on them

Comment: I found a good solution , also ask your official reposition and this is what they said to me: The AniJS behavior is the below:
1 - The library script is loaded.
2 - By default AniJS travel through the current DOM nodes.

If you add another DOM elements dinamically(using angularJS) with new data-anijs sentences after this moment , you need to call the AniJS run function using Javascript.

//Traveled the DOM scope parsing all nodes with data-anijs tag.
AniJS.run();